# Selecting top 5 most count countries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hello I need to take most countable countries from DB. how it looks like:

```
id name country
1  fsdf Sweden
2  dfdf Brazil
3  fgfg Sweden
4  gfgg Germany
5  fgfg Germany
6  fgfg Poland
7  fdff Germany
8  iuii Brazil
9  tyyt Sweden
10 tyut Sweden
11 gfgf Germany
12 fdff Holland
```

And I want output from this - from the most count like:

```
1 Germany count 4
2 Sweden count 4
3 Brazil count 2
4 Poland count 1
5 Holand coun 1
```

I was tried with something like this but not working

```
$top5 = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT top 5 country, count(*)
from list_ots
group by country
order by country desc");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($top5)) {
    echo $row["country"];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax in MySQL uses `LIMIT`, not `TOP`:

```
select country, count(*) as cnt
from list_ots
group by country
order by cnt desc
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use must use `LIMIT` to get top 5:

```
SELECT country, count(*) as count
FROM list_ots
GROUP BY country
ORDER by count desc
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

select top 5 Country,Count(*) as CountryCount FROM list_ots Group By Country Order By CountryCount Desc